# Unable to print anything from java:

Tags: java, printing

I'm unable to print through my thermal printer (Epson TM-T81). When I print, I'm getting white paper only and nothing printed on it. What could be the cause? I'm using the following code:

```
public void printThisBill()
  {

        DefaultTableModel mod = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
      DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
       DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
       //get current date time with Date()
       Date date = new Date();
          Date time = new Date();
            String Date = dateFormat.format(date);
      String Time = timeFormat.format(time);


      String Header = 
                "   ****Sweets Shop****       \n"
              + "Date: "+Date+"     Time: "+Time+"\n"
              + "---------------------------------\n"
              + "Name          Qty    Rate     Amt\n"
              + "---------------------------------\n";

       String amt=    "\n \n \nTotal Amount = "+amt()+"\n"
              + "Tax ="+tax()+ "\n"
              + "*********************************\n"
              + "Thank you. \n";

           String bill = Header;
      int i =0;
      do
      {

      String name =     ""+ mod.getValueAt(i, 2);
      String qty =      ""+mod.getValueAt(i, 3);
      String rate =     ""+mod.getValueAt(i, 4);
      String amount =   ""+mod.getValueAt(i, 6);


      String items = 

              name+"\t"+qty+"\t"+rate+"\t"+amount+"\n";
       bill = bill+ items;       
      i++;
      }
      while(i <= mod.getRowCount()-1);
      bill = bill+amt;




      System.out.println(bill);
      printCard(bill);
      dispose();


  }
```

and to create the graphics and print I'm using the following code:

```
 public static void printCard(final String bill ){



    Printable contentToPrint = new Printable(){
       @Override
       public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
       if (pageIndex >0){return NO_SUCH_PAGE;} //Only one page

       Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graphics.create(); //Cast to Graphics2D object
                g.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY()); //Match origins to imageable area

                    g.drawString (bill, 0, 0); //Print Hello World at offset (100, 100)
                return PAGE_EXISTS; //Page exists (offsets start at zero!)
            }


    };  
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    job.setPrintable(contentToPrint);
    //You can show a print dialog before printing by job by wrapping the following blocks with a conditional statement if(job.printDialog()){...}
    try {
        job.print();
    } catch (PrinterException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }



}
```

Comment: Can you print from outside Java?

Comment: Can you print to other printers?

Comment: Repost of [Printing reciepts with thermal printer in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505070/printing-reciepts-with-thermal-printer-in-java)

Comment: Yes! I'm able to print outside java but haven't tried it on any other printer yet.

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
g.drawString(bill,0,0);
```

to this

```
graphics.drawString(bill,0,0);
```

Comment: That's not making any difference! :(

Comment: I have done this same thing in one of my applications and I only had two differences from your code, the one you just tried and I didn't use .create() on graphics. It just said Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graphics; Other than that...I'm stumped lol