# Java Printing the content of the textarea to the printer

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtextarea

I'm trying to create a program that will print what is written in the jTextArea
my problem is that when the printDialog pops out and I pressed OK the printer doesn't print
or when I changed the properties to *Paper Source* to *Cont.Feed- No Break*, it gives a blank page I'm trying to print on a thermal receipt printer

here is my code

```
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws
                                                    PrinterException {

    if (page > 0) {
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY()-55);

    frameToPrint.print(g);

    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
     job.setPrintable(this);
     boolean ok = job.printDialog();
     if (ok) {
         try {
              job.print();
         } catch (PrinterException ex) {

         }
     }
}

public PrintUIWindow(JFrame f) {
    frameToPrint = f;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Print UI Example");
    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
       public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {System.exit(0);}
    });

    JLabel label1=new JLabel("Selling Bill",JLabel.CENTER);
    JLabel label2=new JLabel("Customer Name :Mahmoud Saleh       ",JLabel.LEFT);
    JLabel label3=new JLabel("Buying Date :29/8/2008             ",JLabel.LEFT);
    JLabel label4=new JLabel("Book Buyed :Java Printing          ",JLabel.LEFT);
    JLabel label5=new JLabel("Number : 6 Copies                  ",JLabel.LEFT);
    JLabel label6=new JLabel("Total Price :600 $                 ",JLabel.LEFT);

    label1.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 13));
    label2.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 13));
    label3.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 13));
    label4.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 13));
    label5.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 13));
    label6.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 13));

    JButton printButton = new JButton("Print This Window");
    printButton.addActionListener(new PrintUIWindow(f));
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,1));
    panel.add(label1);
    panel.add(label2);
    panel.add(label3);
    panel.add(label4);
    panel.add(label5);
    panel.add(label6);
    f.setSize(300,300);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.add(printButton,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Don't swallow the PrinterException ex in the catch block. Do you have any exceptions there?

Comment: You might want to look at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505070/printing-reciepts-with-thermal-printer-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the exact thing that you are asking about. Hope this can be of help:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/336165/GUI/java/print-text-text-area

It gives answer to the topic of your question :)