# Thermal Printing in java using DocFlavor

Tags: java, printing, thermal-printer

I am new to DocFlavor java .
Anyone please help to start like I have simple text file and want to print on thermal printer ,which will be suitable DocFlavor type ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends...If you want to print from a txt file then AUTO_SENSE or PostScript are ussually good ideas.

```
DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.POSTSCRIPT;
```

or
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;

Here is a Snippet as an example.

```
    PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("C:*PATH_TO_STRING_HERE"));

    PrintRequestAttributeSet  pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    pras.add(new Copies(1));        
    flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(in, flavor, null);

    DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
    PrintJobWatcher pjw = new PrintJobWatcher(job);
    job.print(doc, pras);
```

I got this code when i was trying to figure out how to use my thermal receipt printer...If you want a more thourough explanation. IF you need a more in depth answer...

[Then go here !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505070/printing-reciepts-with-thermal-printer-in-java)

NOTE if you need to print out charactesr such as ä, ö or å then this will propably not work well as they will be obscured... I do not know how to print out special characters.

Sincerly...

//Orville

For more info on docflavors..

[Go here !](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/DocFlavor.html)

Comment: Thanks for your comment ..This code will print content which are there in text file ,but how I can set paper width etc with the help of text file .. text file should have [definition] ,[Header],[Detail] etc .so that text file should contain x,y coordinate of statement which I want to print and font size and etc.

Comment: Concept behind this is when I give my software to customer ,then customer can change font size etc  with the help of template but the main code (Java file )

Comment: What is the model of the printer you are using ? There are different byte commands you can send depending on what model which includes information on layout and so forth. Also if i may ask what is it you want to do with the txt file ? Do you want to use it as a receipt ?

Comment: I see but what thermal printer are you using ?

Comment: For cinema ticket printing module I have to do ,and printer is TSC printer ..to adjust paper roll size and content location and font I need template ( Text file )

Comment: Here I got link for TSC TDP 274 PRINTER Specification ,how can I run this ?http://www.tscprinters.com/cms/upload/download_en/TSPL_TSPL2_Programming.pdf

Comment: I was able to give an answer to the question at hand. If you want to i will try to help you with the additional questions but you need to ask them separately so that your questions will be more usefull for others who have a similar problem ^^ So if my answer was able to provide you with a docflavor that would help you then accept my answer as the "correct " answer. I think I might be able to help you out with the other questions if you ask them separately.

Comment: Can You please help me with this