# How partially cut the paper in EPSON TM-T88IV printer using java/kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, epson

I'm following this document.
In that [document](https://www.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=87) the value for the partially cut is the following.

```
   fun finit(): String {
        val FeedAndCut = byteArrayOf(29, 'V'.toByte(), 66, 0)
        var s = String(FeedAndCut)
        val DrawerKick = byteArrayOf(27, 70, 0, 60, 120)
        s += String(DrawerKick)
        commandSet += s
        return s
    }
```

complete code can be found on the following answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/21495620/2769917

I have tried different code from the document but nothing is working.

I have the following printer. **EPSON TM-T88IV**

Comment: What you mean when you say "nothing is working"? Code fails to compile? There is a runtime error? Cut is not done? Cut is done, but in the wrong place?

Comment: `Char.toByte()` is deprecated since Kotlin 1.5, so `'V'.toByte()` should be replaced with `'V'.code.toByte()` or just `86`

Comment: `DrawerKick` bytearray seems to be incorrect. Second number should be `112`, not `70` (see https://www.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=195), you probably copied it from the line for `Hex` format